# Python : IndexError: list index out of range error in ADX

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program for calculating ADX for stockprice , data is saved in a SQL table from which it is read and then trying to calculate ADX and getting IndexError: list index out of range. I am very new in Python so might be making some novice mistake. Please help

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect(
"DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=localhost\SQL2016;Database=StockAnalysis;uid=PythonUser;pwd=PythonUser")

cursor = con.cursor()
sql = """

select distinct stockname from tempPythonLookup
where stockname in 
(
'Reliance'
)
order by stockname

"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)


for row in df:
df = df.set_index(df.stockname)
df = df[['stockname']]
StockNameList=list(df.stockname)
print StockNameList

for x in StockNameList:
  #  print x
    sql2 = """
        select top 20 StockName,StockActivityDate,OpenPrice,HighPrice,LowPrice,ClosePrice,Volume from StockPrices where stockname=? order by stockactivitydate  
        """
    df = pd.read_sql(sql2, con, params=[x])
    #df = df.set_index(df.StockActivityDate)
    df = df[['StockName','StockActivityDate','OpenPrice','HighPrice','LowPrice','ClosePrice','Volume']]
    # price = df.ClosePrice.iloc[:100]

   # price = df.ClosePrice
    date = df.StockActivityDate
    openp = df.OpenPrice
    highp = df.HighPrice
    lowp = df.LowPrice
    closep = df.ClosePrice
    volume = df.Volume

    print date,openp,lowp,highp,closep

    def TR (d,c,h,l,o,yc):
        x = h-l
        y = abs(h-yc)
        z = abs(l-yc)

        if y <= x >= z:
            TR = x
        elif x <= y >= z:
            TR = y
        elif x <= z >= y:
            TR = z

            print 'TR'
            print x
            print y
            print z
        return d, TR


    def DM (d,o,h,l,c,yo,yh,yl,yc):
        moveUp = h-yh
        moveDown = yl-l


        if 0 < moveUp > moveDown:
             PDM = moveUp
        else:
             PDM = 0

        if 0 < moveDown >moveUp:
                NDM=moveDown
        else:
              NDM = 0

              print 'moveupdown'
              print moveDown
              print moveUp
        return d, PDM , NDM





    def ExpMovingAverage (values, window):
            weights = np.exp(np.linspace(-1., 0., window))
            weights /= weights.sum()
            a = np.convolve(values, weights, mode= 'full') [:len(values)]
            a[:window] = a[window]

            print 'expmovavg'
            print a

            return a

    def calcDIs():

            x = 1
            TRDates = []
            TrueRanges = []
            PosDMs = []
            NegDMs = []

            while x < len(date):
                    TRDate, TrueRange = TR(date[x],closep[x],highp[x],lowp[x],openp[x],closep[x-1])
                    TRDates.append(TRDate)
                    TrueRanges.append(TrueRange)

                    DMdate, PosDM, NegDM = DM(date[x], openp[x], highp[x], lowp[x],closep[x],openp[x-1],highp[x-1],lowp[x-1],closep[x-1])
                    PosDMs.append(PosDM)
                    NegDMs.append(NegDM)

                    x+= 1

            print len (PosDMs)


            expPosDM = ExpMovingAverage(PosDMs,14)
            expNegDM = ExpMovingAverage(NegDMs, 14)
            ATR = ExpMovingAverage(TrueRanges, 14)


            xx = 0
            PDIs = []
            NDIs= []

            while xx < len (ATR):
                PDI=100*(expPosDM[xx]/ATR[xx])
                PDIs.append(PDI)

                NDI = 100 * (expNegDM[xx] / ATR[xx])
                NDIs.append(NDI)

                xx+=1
                return PDIs, NDIs


    def ADX():
            PositiveDI, NegativeDI = calcDIs()

            print len(PositiveDI)
            print len (NegativeDI)
            print len (date[1:])

            print ('printDIs')
            print (PositiveDI)
            print (NegativeDI)

            xxx = 0
            DXs= []

            while xxx< len(date[1:]):
                    print ('dates')
                    print(date)
                    DX=100*((abs(PositiveDI[xxx]-NegativeDI[xxx]) /(PositiveDI[xxx]+NegativeDI[xxx])))
                    DXs.append(DX)
                    xxx+=1

            print len(DXs)
            print 'DXs'
            print (DXs)
            ADX = ExpMovingAverage(DXs,14)

            print len(ADX)
            print len(date[1:])
            print ADX

    ADX()


con.close()
```

Below is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       0     20160101
>         File "C:/Users/SubhroSaha/PycharmProjects/StockMachineLearning/ADXCalc.py",
>   line 177, in 
>           ADX()
>         File "C:/Users/SubhroSaha/PycharmProjects/StockMachineLearning/ADXCalc.py",
>   line 164, in ADX
>       DX=100*((abs(PositiveDI[xxx]-NegativeDI[xxx]) /(PositiveDI[xxx]+NegativeDI[xxx]))) 1     20160104
>        IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that the index xxx doesn't exist in the data structure PositiveDI or NegativeDI.

So for example if I have the list l = [0,1] and I call l[3] it will give that same error.

I suggest to analyse what are the values for and the shapes of PositiveDI and NegativeDI, you will find and incongruence there.